# Error in handsontable numbro library, which happens only in production build

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, handsontable

I am getting the following error when adding a row to my handsontable instance:

> core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:15724 ERROR RangeError: toFixed() digits argument must be between 0 and 100
>       at Number.toFixed ()
>       at h (numbro.min.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1)
>       at numbro.min.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1

Full error:
[image]

The weird thing is, that I only get this error on `ng build -prod` (or with the `--optimization` flag).

Using the debugger is therefore tricky, as the js has been compiled, however using `console.log()` I narrowed it down to this handsontable call:

```
hot.alter('insert_row');
```

After reading about this handsontable [compilation issue](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4978), I'm in the process of refactoring the project to enable `strict:true` in `tsconfig.json` but this is turning out to be quite a bit of work.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

versions:

- Angular 7.2
- Handsontable 7.0.0 (but issue also happens in v6)
- Typescript 3.2.4

I do not use the `numbro` library anywhere in my code, it is purely a dependency of `handsontable` (no other libraries in my project use it either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's not releated to Handsontable version. One of the dependencies Numbro in `v2.1.2` have introduced conflict[1] with Webpack TerserPlugin (the default minfier).

Handsontable `v7.0.1` will fix this issue by downgrading numbro dependency. Or you can install it right now: `npm i numbro@2.1.1` and Handsontable will use your version.

[1] https://github.com/BenjaminVanRyseghem/numbro/issues/402#issuecomment-471586507